# rootにrwxの権限が与えられているのに、書き込みが許可されない

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

#### 前提

閲覧ありがとうございます。

Raspberry pi 4で、特定のフォルダにファイルが追加されるのを検知し、追加されたファイルを開くというシステムを作るために、incronを使いたいです。しかし、rootユーザーの権限が無いようで、先に進めず困っています。
利用環境は、macOSからssh接続しているRaspberry pi 4のターミナルです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

まずジョブを登録しようとして、
`$ incrontab -e`
というコマンドが、許可がないために実行できませんでした。

そこで、/etc/incron.allowというファイルに、権限を許可するユーザーの名前を記入する必要があるということで,
incron.allowに書き込みをしようとしたところ、open() failed:許可がありませんと出てしまいました。

権限をls -lで確認したところ、
rwxr----- 1 root incron 0 12月 3 2019 incron.allow
となっておりました。
rootでログインしましたが書き込めず、またchmod u+w incron.allowなども試しましたが、結局書き込みの許可はされませんでした。

何が悪いのかこれ以上わからず、途方にくれております。なぜincron.allowに書き込めないのか、どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、chmod a+rwx incron.allowdeで全てのユーザーに許可したら書き込めるようになりました…これはどういうことでしょうか？

Comment: `id` コマンドの実行結果を教えて下さい。